# Spring And Kotlin Query

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

How can I achieve this query

```
select *
from table t
where name like '%Ami%'
order by (name = 'Ami') desc, length(col);
```

(just the sort part)

Using springframework Sort..

What I tried is

```
Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "name") // But I need to sort by name = 'Ami'
Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "name" = 'Ami'") // throws an error 
JpaSort.unsafe(Sort.Direction.DESC, "name" = 'Ami'") // throws an error
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the documentation has an example almost identical to your question:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.4.5/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting

> However, using Sort together with @Query lets you sneak in
> non-path-checked Order instances containing functions within the ORDER
> BY clause. This is possible because the Order is appended to the given
> query string. By default, Spring Data JPA rejects any Order instance
> containing function calls, but you can use JpaSort.unsafe to add
> potentially unsafe ordering.

Comment: Wouldn't say that the example is almost identical, from what I see, it's nowhere near

Comment: No? It's using a sort along with an order by on the length of a column like you code snippet does - seems pretty similar to me :-)